# How to setup the Pre-Chat form for Live Agent in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

I am newbie to the `salesforce` and working on the `Live Agent` setup and its other useful features. Now I am looking to implement the `Pre-Chat form`, but I dont see the option to choose form. I see the below, Could you please guide what setting needs to be done ?

[image]

I have created a custom VF page and now I want to choose that form. But I dont see that option. I created the Pre-chart form using : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_pre_chat_forms_code_sample.htm

Answer (score 0):

For that we need to register the site for your own force.com site like below and then only you will be able to see the

[image]

And Now you will be able to see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Paste the URL of the page eg. https://cs-19.salesforce.com/apex/PreChatForm in the Pre Chat Form field